# How to convert an Image to Redscale?

Tags: c, opencv

I was playing with the light and color of pixels of an image in OpenCV. I came across the redscale effect. How to implement it in OpenCV? i have tried several ways to manipulating the pixel RGB values. But i have a feeling that i might need to use HSV color space... pls help.

Comment: I found no information on this technique (so far) for digital images.

Comment: redscale effect looks very interesting. the flood of yellow color looks amazing in some images. but i am not getting any idea on how to implement.. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to create Javascript which converts image into mode similar to [redscale effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redscale).

**EDIT:**
I simplified redscale effect and made it closer to the 'real' one.

```
<html>
<body>

<script type='text/javascript'> 
function AppyRedscale(img) {
  width = 200;
  height = 150;
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  cnt = canvas.getContext("2d");
  cnt.drawImage(img,0,0);
  imageData = cnt.getImageData(0,0,width, height);
  imageDataNew = cnt.createImageData(width, height);

  for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      rgb = getPixel(imageData,x,y);
      k = rgb[2]/255;
      rgb[0] = Mix(k,rgb[0],255);
      rgb[1] = Mix((1-k)*(1-k),rgb[1],0);
      rgb[2] = Mix(k,rgb[2],0);
      setPixel(imageDataNew, x, y, rgb, 0xff);
    }
  }

  cnt.putImageData(imageDataNew, 0, 0);

 };

function Mix(k,x,y) {
  return (1-k)*x + k*y;
};

function setPixel(imageData, x, y, rgb, a) {
    index = (x + y * imageData.width) * 4;
    imageData.data[index+0] = rgb[0];
    imageData.data[index+1] = rgb[1];
    imageData.data[index+2] = rgb[2];
    imageData.data[index+3] = a;
};

function getPixel(imageData, x, y) {
    index = (x + y * imageData.width) * 4;
    return [imageData.data[index+0],
            imageData.data[index+1],
            imageData.data[index+2]
            ];
};
</script> 

<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300"
          style="position: absolute; left: 8; top: 170; z-index: 1;"><br /> 
  Sorry, canvas not supported!<br /> 
</canvas>

<img id="img" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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%3D%3D" width="200" height="150" onload="AppyRedscale(this)"/>

</body>
</html>
```

[JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/an96b385/)

Comment: Interesting. +1 for your efforts.

Comment: Thanks I needed something synchronous. Not too fan of global variables, constants or functions though.

Answer (score 2):

in Processing it's so easy.

```
void redscale() {

  loadPixels();      

  for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
  int r = (int) red(pixels[i]);
  int g = (int) red(pixels[i]);
  int b = (int) red(pixels[i]);    
  int average= (r+g+b)/3;

  pixels[i]= color (255, average, 0);

  updatePixels()

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the note of 0x69 wanted credit for the answer. I'd very much say that he did in fact not answer the question, which refers to OpenCV.

I know that the question is 'old', but I found I might shed some light on the topic.
That which my answer contains, is the approach on how to isolate channels, and subtract these from each other.

My project group and I are in the midst of a project involving c++ and OpenCV 2.3 
(version is very important, since OpenCV 2.1 is coded in normal c. The algorithm however does not differ)

What we needed to do was isolate green, and then subtract the red and blue channels, this was how we did it:

```
void IsolateGreen(Mat mIn, Mat& mOut) 

{

Mat inImg (mIn.rows, mIn.cols, CV_8UC3, Scalar(1,2,3));
inImg.data = mIn.data;
Mat channelRed (inImg.rows, inImg.cols, CV_8UC1);
Mat channelGreen (inImg.rows, inImg.cols, CV_8UC1);
Mat channelBlue (inImg.rows, inImg.cols, CV_8UC1);
Mat outImg[] = {channelRed, channelGreen, channelBlue};

int fromTo[] = { 0,2, 1,1, 2,0};
mixChannels( &inImg, 1, outImg, 3, fromTo, 3);

mOut = (channelGreen) - (channelRed + channelBlue);

threshold(mOut, mOut, 10, 255, THRESH_BINARY);

erode(mOut, mOut, Mat(), Point (-1,-1), 1);
dilate(mOut, mOut, Mat(), Point(-1,-1), 3);

}
```

That which I was thinking you could use was these parts of it

```
void IsolateGreen(Mat mIn, Mat& mOut) 
{
    Mat inImg (mIn.rows, mIn.cols, CV_8UC3, Scalar(1,2,3));
inImg.data = mIn.data;
Mat channelRed (inImg.rows, inImg.cols, CV_8UC1);
Mat channelGreen (inImg.rows, inImg.cols, CV_8UC1);
Mat channelBlue (inImg.rows, inImg.cols, CV_8UC1);
Mat outImg[] = {channelRed, channelGreen, channelBlue};

int fromTo[] = { 0,2, 1,1, 2,0};
mixChannels( &inImg, 1, outImg, 3, fromTo, 3);

mOut = channelGreen;
}
```

The essential part here is the mixChannels function, 
read more on 
http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=mixchannels#mixchannels

It took some time to understand. And the result will give one or more grayscale images representing individual channels. (You can always do a similar conversion to have the channel you want, mixed to a single channel in an RGB picture, if you want to be able to see that it is red. It's all about intensities, eh :3 )

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this (pixel by pixel):

1. convert to grayscale (ignoring transparency for now)
2. set the RGB values to the color you want to replace black with (red in this case)
3. use the grayscale as transparency (`255 - grayscale` as opacity)

Pseudocode:

```
const grayscale = inputRed * 0.2126 + inputGreen * 0.7152 +
    inputBlue * 0.0722
const outputRed = 255
const outputGreen = 0
const outputBlue = 0
const outputAlpha = (255 - grayscale) * inputAlpha / 255
```

Note: all inputs including alpha are considered between 0 and 255 and so outputAlpha will be too.
You'll need to adapt the code if you work with alpha between 0 and 1.

Answer (score -1):

I have converted this code to opencv in a very simple way. since opencv considers the color as bgr and not rgb, i made some changes. the code works fine ...please edit if there is any mistake.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( "D:/test.jpg" );
    cvShowImage("Input", img );
    int x,y;
    double k;
    CvScalar s;

    for (x = 0; x < img->width;  x++ )
    {
        for(y = 0; y < img->height;  y++)
        {

            s = cvGet2D(img, y, x);
            k = s.val[0]/255;

            s.val[0] = (1-k) * (1-k) * s.val[0];
            s.val[1] = k * s.val[1];
            s.val[2] = (1-k) * s.val[2] + k * 255;

            cvSet2D(img, y, x, s);

        }
    }
    cvShowImage("Output", img );
    cvWaitKey(0);

    cvReleaseImage(&img);   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: -1. Why ? Because you accepted your own answer which really is mine... You have no conscience.

Comment: i am sorry that you misunderstood me totally. of course i credited you your great answer. but just because i was implementing this in OpenCV, i tried to convert your code in OpenCV and posted it here if there was anything wrong. In the "Add Comment" i couldnt post the codes, so i posted it as an answer... please dont misunderstand. i had no ill intentions. your answer helped me immensely.

Comment: No. You don't credited my answer. If you want to credit my answer - mark it as solved. Because really your answer is just plagiarism (my copied algorithm).

Comment: @0x69 where can i mark it as solved? i am not a registered user, so my activities are limited here...

Comment: @0x69 .. done.  if you can check the OpenCV code that i made based on your codes. let me know if it is correct. after that i will delete the 2nd answer also...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know OpenCV, but you can leave your answer here, it may be useful for other openCV developers ...